# Writing one-dimensional array into two-dimensional

Tags: c#, arrays, f#

Lets say I have an array of chars which I have inputted from in console. How can I write them into two-dimensional array in the following way:

1   6   11  16  21

2   7   12  17  22

3   8   13  18  23

4   9   14  19  24

5   10  15  20  25

Or would it be better to use Lists?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to fill matrix 5*5 with array of chars I have inputted from console. Thats fro now. Eventually, I must implement 'double transposition' - method of encrypting.

Comment: So you'll start coding in f# or c# depending on the answers?

Comment: No, I have tried both. And I had 4 same columns or whole matrix of the same chars etc.

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted into oblivion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have the inputs in a single-dimensional array of length 25:

```ml
let inputs = [| 1 .. 25 |]
```

You can create a two-dimensional array that stores the data in a 5x5 grid using the `Array2D.init` function:

```ml
let arr = Array2D.init 5 5 (fun i j -> inputs.[j*5 + i])
```

The function initializes the array using the specified size (first two parameters) and calls the provided function to fill the value for every element of the array. By accessing the element at index `j*5 + i`, you get the structure that you wanted in your sample.

**EDIT** You cannot append a row to an array (array has a fixed size), but you can easily create a larger array and copy data there:

```ml
let bigger = Array2D.zeroCreate 6 5
// Copy the whole contents of the original array
bigger.[0..4, 0..4] <- arr     
// Write new data to the last row
bigger.[5..5, 0..4] <- array2D [[5;10;15;20;25]]
```

Comment: is it possible to append a row [0,*] to this newly created array?

Answer (score 0):

If you know size of 2D array before inputting the numbers/chars, just use proper loops to input in right places. If not, and you need to rewrite from array to 2D array("Table") use loop

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
       array2D[j,i] = array[j+i*5]
```

That will go trough every char in an array, and put them in right places in 2D array.

Comment: -1 for not using F#. Just kidding. ;-)